# How to retain line terminator characters when calling Files.readAllLines

Tags: java, file

I am parsing a file line by line like so:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The problem is that I need to retain the line terminator characters at the end of each line (because I need to do some "quoted-printable" decoding of some of the lines in the file, and the line terminator matters in these cases).

My file format looks like this:

```
From: test2@test.com
To: test@test.com
Subject: Email subject
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


Please see the following articles:

Joe Ben, Wed, 6/6:  Businesses vie for blackout exemptions:=20
The PUC must decide who should be spared, and the applicant list is very lo=
ng

Joe Bem, Wed, 6/6: PG&E, ISO agree to court order on power bills

Sac Bee, Wed, 6/6:  Peter Schrag: Turning up the heat in Houston and=20
Washington  (Editorial)
```

I could read the whole file as an array of bytes but then this becomes inconvenient for me because it is more convenient for me to parse the headers in the email as lines of text.

Comment: Adding the separator back using System.lineSeparator() will not necessarily work - it will add the separator for the platform on which the app is being executed, which might not be the platform where the file was created.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, that is not correct. As per docs, it recognizes all three of CRLF/LF/CR.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Good catch. Here's the *relevant* [`readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) Javadoc if anyone else cares.

Comment: @jcm, I don't get it. Why should it matter what line terminator was actually used? The method returns a list of already-parsed lines, so you would just do any processing on them you need, including decoding. It's not like you should do something special if the line ending is LF instead of CRLF. A code that relies on line terminator types is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov that's the problem, the 'quoted-printable' encoding cares whether the line terminator is CRLF or just LF :(

Comment: How so? I understand that it cares about *encoded* line endings, such as =0D=0A vs =0A, but byte-coded line endings shouldn't really matter, should they? AFAIK, they should all be CRLF anyway.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov it treats CRLF as a soft line break which when decoded doesn't put any line break in the output. Other line terminators are treated as normal line terminators. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Comment: “A soft line break consists of an "=" at the end of an encoded line, and does not appear as a line break in the decoded text.”—it doesn't say that it must be CRLF. The [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#page-19) does, but it still enforces an '=' before the line break to make it a soft break. In fact, it even says “Control characters other than TAB, or CR and LF as parts of CRLF pairs, must not appear.” So valid quoted-printable string must never contain just CR or LF anyway (except in encoded form).